# Showing that an operation has inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to show whether or not

> $(a, b) \cdot (c, d) = (ac-bd, ad+bc)$ on the set $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ with the origin deleted forms a group, an abelian group, or neither.

I've shown that it's commutative, associative, has an identity element $(1, 0)$ and am now thoroughly stuck on showing that it ever element in the set has an inverse. The (elementary/arithmetic) algebra just isn't working out for me here. I solved for $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ and got something rather complicated, but then when I plugged it back in to check my answer the algebra is just not working out.

For $a^{-1}$ I got $\dfrac{1+bb^{-1}}{a}$ and for $b^{-1}$ I got $\dfrac{-b}{a^2 +b^2}$.

I google searched the problem ("A Book of Abstract Algebra by Pinter, chapter 3 problem set B problem #4) and the question has already been asked on here but the individual there had a bit more specific of a question, and, in short I didn't find the answers helpful so please don't direct me there. For your reference however, it may be helpful to look at. It talks about complex numbers and such which this book doesn't cover so I'm wondering what the deal with that is...

So, if someone could please find the inverses and plug them back in to ensure they are true for me and give a THOROUGH explanation in doing so, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's a group isomorphic to $C^*=(C-\{0\},\times)$

Comment: I'm new to abstract algebra. That means nothing to me

Comment: $C$ is complex number, $\times$ is standard multiplication

Comment: A notation thing: here it's not accurate to call $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ the coordinates of $(a,b)^{-1}$ , because you haven't specified an operation on $\Bbb R$, just on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$. If you have the "usual" operation on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, that is $(a,b)(a',b')=(aa',bb')$, then it's true that  $(a,b)^{-1}=(a^{-1},b^{-1})$, because you're defining the operation on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ in terms of the operation on $\Bbb R$, but it's not true in general. (It'd be better to write something like "let $(c,d)=(a,b)^{-1}$ then $c=\cdots$ and $d=\cdots$.)

Comment: Oh, good ol' coldnumber, missed correcting me have you? ;) I'm having a little trouble reading that right now cuz my phone doesn't change the "input" math to fancy stuff in the comments, only the answers, but is this basically what you were saying on my last question about how you didn't think it was technically correct to say (a^-1, b^-1) but I should instead write (a, b)^-1? If so, I checked my book and the author does it my way so I felt justified in doing so (not to emotion, I'm sure that's where I got it from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, given $(a,b)$, you are simply trying to find a pair $(c,d)$ such that:

$$ (a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(1,0)$$

This corresponds exactly to the system of two equations:
$$ ac-bd=1$$
$$ bc+ad=0$$

And from this we are trying to solve for $c$ and $d$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. Luckily this is a system of two equations and two variables, and hence some simple algebra gives:
$$ c=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$
$$ d=\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$$

Therefore the pair $\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}, \frac{-b}{a^2+b^2} \right)$ is the inverse of $(a,b)$.

EDIT: Here are the details of the "simple algebra":
We multiply the first equation by $a$ and the second by $b$ to get:
$$ a^2c-abd=a$$
$$ b^2c+abd=0$$
Adding them together, we get:
$$ c(a^2+b^2)=a$$

And thus, $$ c=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$

Now, from the second equation and our solution for $c$, we know:
$$ d=\frac{-bc}{a}=\frac{-ba}{a(a^2+b^2)}=\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: What I'm struggling with is what you call "simple algebra." I've since found a complex way to get there (look at my comments on the other answer) but I wouldn't call it simple so what exactly are you referring to when you say simple?

Comment: I added all of the details of the "simple algebra" for you to understand.

Comment: Let me know if you do not understand any part of it

Comment: The reason I multipied the first equation by $a$ and the second equation by $b$ is so that the second terms in both equations are opposites, so that the sum eliminates them.

Comment: Have you taken a linear algebra course?

Comment: Yes, your answer makes perfect sense, and this is very similar to the answer I saw online (see my comments on the other answer to this question). My approach to solving it was arguably more difficult. If you want to understand what I did look at my comments in the other answer to the question. Basically, I solved for a inverse in the 1st eqn. Plugged that into the 2nd eqn to solve for b inverse. Got the b inverse you guys got but then DID NOT plug that back into the a inverse eqn to get my a inverse in the same terms if that makes sense.

Comment: No I haven't. I've only taken calc1&2 and a math proof class. This fall in taking multi-dimensional calc, abstract algebra, 1D real analysis, and topology as a sophomore though so I thought it'd be smart to start teaching myself his stuff now haha. Plus, I love math although I'm not all that great at it. Thank you for your comment about why you mult. by a and b by the way; like I said the pdf thing on field complexities or whatever did the same thing, but I didn't see the motivation behind it. I suppose realizing those things would be a good next step to my mathematical maturity! Thanks:)

Comment: I understand what you did. In your post, your answer is completely correct, you just haven't simplified it enough. Regardless, it seems like you actually would not need to in this case. You have shown that inverses exist, and that is all that is required to verify the axiom

Comment: Also, realizing easier ways to solve systems of equations is just something that comes with practice. Keep up the good work, and don't stop getting ahead!

Comment: Thank you! This is such a great community here; I frigging love it

Comment: Welcome to MSE :)

Comment: Fun fact though: this "ordered pair" set is basically the same thing as the complex numbers. If we say $(a,b)=b+ai$, then we can easily verify: $(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$, which is the same thing as saying $(a,b) \cdot (c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$

Comment: You guys are really good at keeping me up till 4am (deflecting responsibility of course)...yeah! In my question I was saying how the other answer to this question on MSE talked about complex numbers. Plus, that online pdf which pointed me in the right direction was obviously about complex numbers due to its title. Now I know what they were talking about! As I said, on my phone the comments don't translate into "pretty math" from the input, only the questions and answers (is it always that way?) so it's a bit hard for me to read what you're saying, plus it's 4am but I'm pretty sure I got it.

Comment: I also don't know much about complex numbers. Only what you get in high school from algebra 2 and precalculus, but basically you factor out an i^2 in what you wrote, to get what the operation the book gave me is.

Answer (score 1):

You were "close":

Instead of using the terms "$a^{-1}$" and "$b^{-1}$" let us introduce the following two functions:

$p_1: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R\\ p_2: \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$

given by:

$p_1(x,y) = x\\ p_2(x,y) = y.$

(we can call these "coordinate function number $1$", and "coordinate function number $2$").

You correctly found that $p_2((a,b)^{-1}) = \dfrac{-b}{a^2 + b^2}$, and that:

$p_1((a,b)^{-1}) = \dfrac{1 + bp_2((a,b)^{-1})}{a}$.

Substituting, we have:

$p_1((a,b)^{-1}) = \dfrac{1 + b\dfrac{-b}{a^2 + b^2}}{a} = \dfrac{\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{a^2 + b^2}  - \dfrac{b^2}{a^2 + b^2}}{a}$

$= \dfrac{a^2}{a^2 + b^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{a} = \dfrac{a}{a^2 + b^2}$.

Then, since $(x,y) = (p_1(x,y),p_2(x,y))$, we have:

$(a,b)^{-1} = \left(\dfrac{a}{a^2+b^2},\dfrac{-b}{a^2 + b^2}\right)$.

To simplify verifying $(a,b)(a,b)^{-1} = (1,0)$, note that:

$(a,b)(a,-b) = (a^2 - (-b^2),ab - ba) = (a^2 + b^2, 0)$

and that for any real number $r$, $(a,b)(rc,rd) = (a(rc) - b(rd), a(rd) + b(rc))$

$= (r(ac - bd), r(ad + bc))$

So letting $r = \dfrac{1}{a^2 + b^2}$, we have:

$(a,b)(ra,-rb) = (r(a^2 + b^2),r0) = (1,0)$.

Comment: Exactly! We figured this out in one of the other answers and through my one doings but thank you!

Comment: @LiamCooney Indeed, you did-however, I daresay you may find the "$p$" functions useful later on when you get to direct products.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to the question "[Proofs with steps of division and setting things not equal to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164325/proofs-with-steps-of-division-and-setting-things-not-equal-to-zero)" use linear algebra or complex arithmetic. Since you've already seen those derivations, I'll skip to the end and be very explicit:
$$(a,b)^{-1}=\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2},\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}\right).$$
The exercise is to verify the identity
$$(a,b)\cdot\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2},\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}\right)=(1,0),$$
which you should do by applying the definition of "$\cdot$" to compute the left-hand side.

Comment: I understand that and with that new value of a^-1 I didn't have before I'm thinking that should be much easier, but that still doesn't explain why I didn't get THAT a^-1 and instead got the one I listed in my question which led to my trouble verifying that it was indeed the inverse. I saw a similar problem online for some class which was covering the complexity of a field which has the same a and b inverse and explained how to get there but it was very arbitrary (multiply one eqn by a, the other by b, and so on and so forth without explaining WHY you were doing that).

Comment: So tour answer still doesn't really answer my question but I think I figured out the problem: is it that my a inverse wasn't in the same "terms" so to speak as my b inverse? I had a inverse in terms of a, b and b inverse whereas I had my b inverse in terms of a and b? I plugged by b inverse back into my original eqn for a inverse and got the a inverse that you got, so I think I'm good. Does that make any sense...?

Comment: I'm not sure from this description what happened. If you're looking for a critique of the work you've done, would you like to show that work?

Comment: I had trouble solving for a and b inverse. I got answers (see above-I got the same b inverse as you but a different a inverse) but if you then try to verify the identity with MY a and b inverse (again the a inverse I got is different than yours...see my original question, I stated what I got, and with the b inverse we both got) it doesn't work. I think this is b/c the a inverse I had was given with a b inverse in it whereas I'd gotten rid of all the inverses in b inverse. If I plug b inverse back into my a inverse eqn in place of the b inverse I have though, I get the same inverse you got.

Comment: Basically what I did was I solved for a inverse in the first eqn. Then plugged this in for a inverse in the 2nd eqn and solved for b inverse and got the same b inverse you did. I then SHOULD have plugged b inverse I just got into the a inverse eqn I used to solve for b inverse in the 2nd eqn but instead left a inverse as it was which I shouldn't have. Does this make more sense now? I'm trying to avoid showing all my work cuz it would take forever to write out and I'm unsure how to post a picture on here. Do you understand what I'm saying though?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but if your expression was equivalent to mine, it should have "worked" when you multiplied by (a,b). Maybe it did work, but you didn't simplify the result enough to find out.

Comment: The b inverse was equivalent but not the a inverse. The $a^-1 = \fract{1+bb^-1}\{a} and so combining that with our b inverse to get (1,0) was obviously difficult. When I simply plug b^-1 back into that a^-1 eqn I just gave I get the a inverse you got and all is well :) Thank you!